# Sending custom email message on devise user creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So I need to send a confirmation email every time a user signs up. There are two ways of signing up -- either when a user hits my login page, or when he is invited by another user. In both cases, I want to send separate types of email (in the second case, I also want to tell them that you were sent invitation by foo@bar.com person etc.). What is the best way to do this? I am using devise for rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [action mailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) for sending email

you can send email by using callback means that if you user sign up then below method call

```
after_create :send_mail_to_xxx_xxx
def send_mail_to_xxx_xxx 
  ... 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Can I pass parameters to it? The problem is that I want to add a couple of parameters to the call that I want to make. Is it also possible in some way?